# Repeat username/password authentication with each call to web service

Tags: web-services, authentication

I am creating a web service to expose to my mobile apps.  I currently am implementing a token based authentication solution (because that what I have done in the past); however, I am struggling in this context to understand why I do not simply pass the username and password each time?  I can maintain the password in RAM while running the Mobile app (encrypted between usages if we want to get overly complicated) and then pass it each time I connect to the server and repeat the hash verification each time.  Of course everything is SSL so there is no more risk in terms of network transfer in doing it each time versus do it once is there?  The only CON I see is that the hash validation process might me more expensive than a token validation - maybe.  Are there other cons I am missing here?

Answer (score 2):

There are a few reasons not to do this:

1. Every time you transmit the information, you open the risk of interception. (Even if that risk is mostly mitigated by using an encryption system such as SSL).
2. Passing a username / password combination on every request implies that you will be checking the combination of them on the server-side with every request. This usually requires an extra database hit and some logic which is unnecessary.
3. If you are passing credentialization such as this on every request, you will need to use SSL for every request - which is expensive overhead. It is much cheaper to send an encrypted authentication token back and forth in plain-text - which only the server-side can read.

This seems like a bit of a hot topic here on SO the last few days, as I've answered several questions about RESTful auth and such. I am providing below some links to those answers - which go much more in-depth. Perhaps if you take a look at the auth schemes I'm proposing - you'll see how it protects you more than simply sending username/password on each request.

[Authentication in RESTful web services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13186455/authentication-in-restful-web-services/13187135#13187135)

[Public facing Authentication mechanisms for REST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12361017/public-facing-authentication-mechanisms-for-rest/13199099#13199099)